# Django request.user.username doesn't work

Tags: django

Hi
I've got a problem with the Django Template system. When I want to check in the template if a user is logged in with:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    # success
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I dont get to the success part. When I use in a view:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'inhalt': 'Not loggged in'})
else:
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'inhalt': 'Succesfully loged in'})
```

it shows me correctly the else part.
Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks Phil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an example of handling the context in [part 4 of the Django tutorial.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial04/) However, in short...

The best way to do this is with Django's auth context proccessor. Make sure you still have it in [your settings](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors). You then need to use [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

This will essentially change your code to this.

```
from django.template import RequestContext
# ...
return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'inhalt': 'Succesfully loged in'
}, RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 5):

Remember to add **'django.core.context_processors.request'** to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings.py

Example:

```
# Context processors
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

And add RequestContext(request):

```
# import
from django.template import RequestContext

# render
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'inhalt': 'Not loggged in'})
else:
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'inhalt': 'Succesfully logged in'}, RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3):

In your python you retrieve the user object that is logged in. I.e define a function get_current_user.

so your response would look something like:

```
class Index(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user= get_current_user()
    templates.render(self, 'mypage.html', user=user)
```

Then on your django template you can simply go like:

```
{% if user %}
  <p>Hallo user {{user.name}}</p>
{% else %}
  <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: +1 The `{{user}}` variable is available by default, unlike the `{{request.user}}` variable. For the latter you have to enable `django.core.context_processors.request`. I find this better for current Django versions although http://stackoverflow.com/a/5301918/781695 is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that either you pass 'request.user' into the renderer.  Or better yet use context based rendering:

```
return render_to_response('index.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The context_instance will use the auth middleware context processor to set the 'user' in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Did you pass in your "user" instance from the view to the template? You need to make sure it is in the same context you pass into the render_to_response(), or whichever rendering method you choose for rendering the view context into the template.